# SQL special text escaping

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, sqlite

I would like to insert the following 4 lines into a database:

```
insert into [formulas] values(6, 'Ár', '@#Idő@/60*@#Órabér@*@#Torzítás@');
insert into [formulas] values(7, 'Idő', 'ceil(((@#Összhossz@/1000)/@~Előtolás@)*100)/100+ceil((@#Lyukszám@*@~Lyuk. idő@/60+@#Anyagtényező@*@#Lyukszám@)*100)/100');
insert into [formulas] values(8, 'Önköltség', '(@!Áramár/h@+@!Csarnokbér/h@+@!Munkás órabér@+@!Szervízköltség@+@~Gáz fogy.@*@#Vágógáz Ár@+3*@!N2 (m3)@)/(@~Előtolás@*60)');
insert into [formulas] values(9, 'Lyukönköltség', '@#Lemezvast.@');
```

These was exported from an SQLite database, and I want them to insert into wamp server's sql database.
Can anybody help me, how to escape these strings?

arnold

Comment: Well, is the destination column VARCHAR or NVARCHAR? If VARCHAR, you need to fix it, then you need to prefix those strings with the N prefix, so `INSERT dbo.tablename(columnname) VALUES(N'Unicode string');`

Comment: I simply made as TEXT the second and the third field.

Comment: TEXT is from the 1990s - it is deprecated and shouldn't be used, especially since it *can't store Unicode data like `Idő`*. You need to use NVARCHAR.

Comment: OK. I'm not a professional programmer. I just make a few "tools" on the computer for myself, to help my daily work. Unfortunately in phpmyadmin's field types list there is no NVARCHAR. Only TEXT, CHAR, VARCHAR, TINYTEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, LONTEXT, and again for BLOB.

Comment: Why do you think they need escaping? What actual problem do you have when importing?

Comment: database engine??  It _sounds_ like you want to insert into MySQL.  If that is correct, please remove the non-mysql database tags so you won't get mis-information.

Answer (score 0):

WAMP has MySQL in it, so I *assume* you are asking how to perform those INSERTs on a MySQL database.

Get rid of the brackets around the table name.

Establish the character set encoding (probably utf8) of the bytes in the source:

```
⚈  (deprecated) mysql interface: mysql_set_charset('utf8'); (assuming PHP 5.2.3 & MySQL 5.0.7) Note: "mysql_" interface is deprecated.
⚈  mysqli interface: mysqli_set_charset('utf8') function. See mysqli_set_charset
⚈  PDO interface: set the charset attribute of the PDO dsn.
```